# Spawning an SKSpriteNode at 10 second intervals in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I would like to spawn an enemy (an `SKSpriteNode`) every ten seconds and increase that time as time goes on. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

P.S. I have tried using a NSTimer but I keep getting an error saying: Cannot invoke 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval' with an argument list of type '(Double, target: GameScene -> () -> GameScene, selector: String, userInfo: nil, repeats: Bool)'

Comment: Please try and see where you get stuck and we'll help you

Comment: @MyGGaN The thing is I don't really know where to start... ._.

Comment: Are you really talking about using timers? What if you read up on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/ and then try to ask a more specific question? Or are you asking about how to create a Sprite and add it to a scene?

Comment: @BaseZen Well I've tried to use NSTimers but they do not work with SpriteKit or at least it didn't work with SpriteKit with me. :/

Answer (score 0):

You're simply calling the parameters incorrectly to the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method.

This API works in a very "old-fashioned" way: they don't take a *closure* but rather a `target` object (on which to call the selector), and String-typed *method selector*.

The `target` is usually just `self`, e.g. the controller that you're working within that started the timer should also receive the timer events.

The `selector` should be simply a hard-coded string: `"handleTimer:"`

so you have:

```
class MyController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        /* Repeats every 10 seconds. handleTimer() can feel free to invalidate
           and re-schedule this timer at a different interval */
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, self, "handleTimer:", nil, true)
    }

    func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
        /* Do my awesome GameKit stuff here, using stored properties to refer to
           all my scene objects. (Since I don't get any params passed in) */
        /* Now play with the timer any way I like, e.g.: */
        let newInterval = timer.timeInterval + 1.0
        timer.invalidate()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(newInterval, self, "handleTimer:", nil, true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! By "using stored properties do you mean do something like: GameScene.[name of sprite here]? When I try to do that my sprite doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: I'd post the whole class if possible then. Hard to know how you've structured everything. But generally, no. `GameScene` is the name of your *class*; within it, `self` is the name of the *instance*, so it would likely be `self.nameOfSprite`. (So we're talking about per-instance stored properties, not per-class stored properties. If those terms don't make sense yet, learn later.)